# Limit messages to every 500 ms

Tags: javascript

I have some websocket that sends around 100's of data per second,I want to limit it to only 1 data per 500 ms.

```
 onMessage(data) {
   console.log(data); // This prints around 100 different times within 1 second
  }
```

I tried something like below , Is this the right approach or is there any other better way to do it ? because this code runs 100 times per second.

```
var lastlog = new Date().getTime();
   onMessage(data) {
        currenttime = new Date().getTime();
        if ( currenttime - lastlog > 500) {
           console.log(data);
           lastlog = new Date().getTime();
        }
  }
```

P.s : I can ignore remaining data and will be able to reduce the 500 ms to 200ms.. that is 5 data per second.

Comment: What do you want to do with messages that come to fast? Do you want to ignore them or add them to a queue to process later?

Comment: I want to ignore them.

Comment: you can also not use a websocket if you dont need to, and just query the server every 500ms with a basic fetch/http request. not sure if that's appropriate for what you're doing but could be an option

Comment: FYI, you're describing throttling. Look around for "JavaScript throttle" and you may find an answer you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it, using the npm package [`throttle-debounce`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce). This method is not "better". It can result is less code typed but you might not want the dependency on the package.

You can use the `throttle` function and specify how many milliseconds until it can be called again. Setting the second argument to `true` prevents the last request from being deffered -https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce#notrailing.

The example below uses the library to throttle how often a button is pressed.

```js
const { throttle } = throttleDebounce

const handleRequest = throttle(500, true, () => {
  console.log('this request will be handled')
})
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/throttle-debounce@3.0.1/umd/index.js'></script>

<button onClick="handleRequest()">Mimick sending message</button>
```

Your use case might look like this:

```js
import { throttle } from 'throttle-debounce'

const onMessage = throttle(500, true, () => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Less lines than your example, but that doesn't mean it's "better".